# Specifying Order of Executing Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, schema, etl

**Issue:**

The order in which my stored procedures are called produces no errors if run independently, but when run as once, yields the following error:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure sp_ETL_S1_tbl1, Line 40
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl1__EE1C17C10200000'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'S1.tbl1'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.
```

**Hypothesis:**

I believe this is due to the first stored procedure containing the `DROP TABLE` statements, and for some reason it doesn't get called first when all the stored procedures are run together.

**Offending Code:**

```
mssql
execute_sps.sql

USE db1;
GO
EXEC sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas;
   EXEC sp_ETL_dbo_tbl1;
   EXEC sp_ETL_dbo_tbl2;
```

**Procedures above defined:**

Stored procedure to create schema and tables.

```
sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas.sql

USE db1;

DROP PROCEDURE sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas
AS

GO
DROP TABLE S1.tbl1
DROP TABLE S1.tbl2

DROP SCHEMA S1;
GO
CREATE SCHEMA S1;
GO
CREATE TABLE S1.tbl1(
    SalesGroupID       varchar(20)
        NOT NULL         PRIMARY KEY
,   SalesGroupType     int
,   SalesGroup         varchar(20)

)
;
GO
CREATE TABLE S1.tbl2(
    [NameID]                    int
        NOT NULL                    PRIMARY KEY
,   [FirstName]                 varchar(50)
,   [MiddleName]                varchar(50)
,   [LastName]                  varchar(50)
,   [LastUpdated]               datetime
)
;
```

Stored procedures to ETL data from `(olddb.tbl1, olddb.tbl2)` to `(db1.S1.tbl1 , db1.S1.tbl2)`

```
USE db1;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE sp_ETL_S1_tbl1;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ETL_S1_tbl1
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#SalesGroup') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN DROP TABLE #SalesGroup END

SELECT
    [SalesGroupID]
,   [SalesGroupType]     
,   [SalesGroup]         
INTO #SalesGroup
FROM olddb.tbl1
;

INSERT INTO db1.S1.tbl1(
    [SalesGroupID]       
,   [SalesGroupType]     
,   [SalesGroup]              
)
SELECT
    [SalesGroupID]    
,   [SalesGroupType]
,   [SalesGroup] 
FROM #SalesGroup
```

```
USE db1;
GO
DROP PROCEDURE sp_ETL_S1_tbl2;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ETL_S1_tbl2
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
IF object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Names') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN DROP TABLE #Names END

SELECT
    [NameID]
,   [FirstName] 
,   [MiddleName]    
,   [LastName]  
,   [LastUpdated]
INTO #Names
FROM olddb.tbl2
;

INSERT INTO db1.S1.tbl2(
    [NameID]                    
,   [FirstName]                 
,   [MiddleName]                
,   [LastName]                  
,   [LastUpdated]               
)
SELECT
    [NameID]                    
,   [FirstName]                 
,   [MiddleName]                
,   [LastName]                  
,   [LastUpdated]               

FROM #Names
```

Comment: Do you need to drop and rebuild the table each time? Could you get away with `IF EXISTS` and `TRUNCATE` if it does?

Does the behaviour change if you put `GO` in between each `EXEC` in execute_sps.sql?

Comment: You are missing the definition for the `sp_ETL_dbo_tbl1` procedure.

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried to protect sensitive information by obscuring the names but you've screwed it up. The error message mentions sp_ETL_S1_tbl1 the definition for which is nowhere in your question. Further the "Offending Code" references SP names different from what you post. Please edit the question to correct the names.

Comment: The `sp_` prefix has a special meaning in SQL Server. Do not use it for user code. See [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: In reply to the above; I've added the `sp_ETL_dbo_tbl1` procedure, and corrected the name typos. I will update the `sp_` prefixes in my reply to answer, but leave it uncorrected in the question,  given it provided valuable insight I did not know prior.

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question, but post it separately as an answer if it differs enough from the existing answer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will execute the statements in a batch one at a time, from top to bottom. Each statement will complete before the next is executed. In your case the this means the first SP runs to completion, then the second one starts and runs to completion, then the third starts and runs to completion. There is no circumstance in which anything else can occur.

Your error is with how you define stored procedure sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas. You use the GO command as if it were part of the stored procedure definition. It is not. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go#remarks) says

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.
>
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server.

When you run file sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas.sql through SSMS (or any other utility) the statements from the beginning of the file to the first GO are sent to the SQL Server engine. When that call returns the statements between the first GO and the second GO are sent, and so on. Eventually all the batches in that file are processed and the result is what you expect.

Or it is mostly what you expect. The definition of the stored procedure is just a stub consisting of the three lines

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas
AS
```

You can verify this by looking at what [SQL Server has stored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql) internally as the definition of that SP:

```
exec sp_helptext 'sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas';
```

You'll see just those three lines.

When you run the batch consisting of the three SPs together it is this empty stub which is executed. Syntactically it is correct so you do not get an error. But it has no statements so no tables are dropped and all the data remains in tact. Hence when a subsequent SP tries to re-load the same data there are key violations.

If you need to batch statements within a stored procedure you can use the `EXECUTE('...');` [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Michael Green's comments, and explanation helped to identify the problem. Particularly, calling `exec sp_helptext 'sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas';` displayed an empty stub, as explained, which was not in fact the procedure trying to be executed.

Altering `sp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas.sql`, replacing `GO` with `EXEC` at all batch levels of the procedure, required the least adjustments with the expected result set. Calling the prior `sp_helptext` command shows the fully intended statements for execution when tested.

```
usp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas.sql
/* Per Michael's comment, 'sp_' should be replaced with 'usp_' for user
stored procedures*/

USE db1;

DROP PROCEDURE usp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ETL_db1_CreateSchemas
AS

BEGIN
EXEC('
DROP TABLE S1.tbl1
DROP TABLE S1.tbl2

DROP SCHEMA S1
')
;
EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA S1')
;
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE S1.tbl1(
    SalesGroupID       varchar(20)
        NOT NULL         PRIMARY KEY
,   SalesGroupType     int
,   SalesGroup         varchar(20)

)
')
;
EXEC('
CREATE TABLE S1.tbl2(
    [NameID]                    int
        NOT NULL                    PRIMARY KEY
,   [FirstName]                 varchar(50)
,   [MiddleName]                varchar(50)
,   [LastName]                  varchar(50)
,   [LastUpdated]               datetime
)
')
;
```